# How to find the difference between each subsequent pair of DataFrame.index values in pandas?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas

I have created a `DataFrame` in order to process some data, and I want to find the difference in time between each pair of data in the `DataFrame`. Prior to using pandas, I was using two numpy arrays, one describing the data and the other describing time (an array of `datetime.datetime`s). With the data in arrays, I could do `timearray[1:] - timearray[:-1]` which resulted in an array (of n-1 elements) describing the gap in time between each pair of data.

In pandas, doing `DataFrame.index[1] - DataFrame.index[0]` gives me the result I want – the difference in time between the two indices I've picked out. However, doing `DataFrame.index[1:] - DataFrame.index[:-1]` does not yield an array of similar results, instead simply being equal to `DataFrame.index[-1]`. Why is this, and how can I replicate the numpy behaviour in pandas?

Alternatively, what is the best way to find datagaps in a `DataFrame` in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use shift to offset the date and use it to calculate the difference between rows.

```
# create dummy data
import pandas as pd
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=90, freq='h')
# shift a copy of the date column and subtract from the original date
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':range(1,91),'date':rng})
df['time_gap'] = df['date']- df['date'].shift(1)
```

To use this set your index to a column temporarily by using `.reset_index()` and `.set_index('date')` to return the date column to an index if required.

Comment: So I tried doing `timeDelta = df.index - df.index.shift(1)` and that generated `ValueError: Cannot shift with no offset`. I then tried `timeDelta = df.reset_index()['index'] - df.reset_index()['index'].shift(1)`, which worked brilliantly, so thank you!